# What actually happens when broadcasting a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I was playing around with NumPy and I've written simple function

```
>   def euclid_dist(x, y):
...    return sqrt((x-y).transpose().dot(x-y))
```

But now when I try

```
> x = arange(1,4).reshape(3,1)
> y = array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]).transpose()
> z = euclid_dist(x, y)
> z

array([[  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ],
       [  0.        ,   5.19615242,   7.34846923,   9.        ],
       [  0.        ,   7.34846923,  10.39230485,  12.72792206],
       [  0.        ,   9.        ,  12.72792206,  15.58845727]])
```

Ok... So, numbers on the diagonal are the things I wanted, but what about the rest? What just happened?

As far as I understand it, `x` is broadcasted, so it 'becomes' something like

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

But what happens after that? It's clearly not element-wise operation. But if it would apply function to every pair of columns of x and y then shouldn't all rows (or columns) of `z` be equal (as all columns of 'broadcasted `x`' are equal)?

Clearly there is something I don't understand and I will appreciate any clarification.

Comment: Read about how it works using shape and strides here http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/advanced_numpy/index.html#life-of-ndarray

Comment: sorry @senderle, one reshape too far ;) fixed it

Comment: I'm sorry again @senderle, I've been working for too long apparently...

Comment: Lol it's no problem I understand your question now -- answering in a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, you are trying to do a column-wise parallel dot product. In other words, for a matrix of vectors `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, you want to take this:

```
[[a1, b1, c1, d1],
 [a2, b2, c2, d2],
 [a3, b3, c3, d3]]
```

To this:

```
[a1 * a1 + a2 * a2 + a3 * a3,
 b1 * b1 + b2 * b2 + b3 * b3,
 c1 * c1 + c2 * c2 + c3 * c3,
 d1 * d1 + d2 * d2 + d3 * d3]
```

In fact, your understanding of broadcasting looks just fine. It's `dot` that doesn't work the way you expect -- it does matrix multiplication. So you get the following results (depending on how you transpose):

```
>>> sqrt((x - y).T.dot(x - y))
array([[ 11.22497216,  11.22497216,  11.22497216],
       [ 11.22497216,  11.22497216,  11.22497216],
       [ 11.22497216,  11.22497216,  11.22497216]])
>>> sqrt((x - y).dot((x - y).T))
array([[  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ],
       [  0.        ,   5.19615242,   7.34846923,   9.        ],
       [  0.        ,   7.34846923,  10.39230485,  12.72792206],
       [  0.        ,   9.        ,  12.72792206,  15.58845727]])
```

The diagonal of the second result is what you're looking for, but the full matrix multiplication does too much extra work. Here's how I usually get just the diagonal, roughly speaking:

```
>>> sqrt(((x - y) * (x - y)).sum(axis=1))
array([  0.        ,   5.19615242,  10.39230485,  15.58845727])
```

In short, you actually want *not* to broadcast in this particular case.